# Gas estimation error - execution reverted { "originalError": { "code": 3, "data": "0xfb7f5079", "message": "execution reverted" } }

Tags: blockchain, solidity, remix, uniswap

I have a contract deployed on the rinkeby testnet. It is basically a clone of uniswapV2.
Whenever I try to call the router contract's addLiquidity/ removeLiquidity/ swapTokens functions this error pops up. All other functions in other contracts are working just fine! Only functions of the router contract are giving this error!

I am unable to rectify this problem at the moment kindly look into this and suggest some ways to make it work! Here is the code for reference:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.10;

import "../interfaces/IKswapPair.sol";
import "../interfaces/IKswapFactory.sol";
import "./KswapLibrary.sol";

contract KswapRouter {
    error ExcessiveInputAmount();
    error InsufficientAAmount();
    error InsufficientBAmount();
    error InsufficientOutputAmount();
    error SafeTransferFailed();

    IKswapFactory factory;

    constructor(address factoryAddress) {
        factory = IKswapFactory(factoryAddress);
    }

    function addLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint256 amountADesired,
        uint256 amountBDesired,
        uint256 amountAMin,
        uint256 amountBMin,
        address to
    )
        public
        returns (
            uint256 amountA,
            uint256 amountB,
            uint256 liquidity
        )
    {
        if (factory.pairs(tokenA, tokenB) == address(0)) {
            factory.createPair(tokenA, tokenB);
        }
        (amountA, amountB) = _calculateLiquidity(
            tokenA,
            tokenB,
            amountADesired,
            amountBDesired,
            amountAMin,
            amountBMin
        );
        address pairAddress = KswapLibrary.pairFor(
            address(factory),
            tokenA,
            tokenB
        );
        _safeTransferFrom(tokenA, msg.sender, pairAddress, amountA);
        _safeTransferFrom(tokenB, msg.sender, pairAddress, amountB);
        liquidity = IKswapPair(pairAddress).mint(to);
    }

    function removeLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint256 liquidity,
        uint256 amountAMin,
        uint256 amountBMin,
        address to
    ) public returns (uint256 amountA, uint256 amountB) {
        address pair = KswapLibrary.pairFor(
            address(factory),
            tokenA,
            tokenB
        );
        IKswapPair(pair).transferFrom(msg.sender, pair, liquidity);
        (amountA, amountB) = IKswapPair(pair).burn(to);
        if (amountA < amountAMin) revert InsufficientAAmount();
        if (amountB < amountBMin) revert InsufficientBAmount();
    }

    function swapExactTokensForTokens(
        uint256 amountIn,
        uint256 amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to
    ) public returns (uint256[] memory amounts) {
        amounts = KswapLibrary.getAmountsOut(
            address(factory),
            amountIn,
            path
        );
        if (amounts[amounts.length - 1] < amountOutMin)
            revert InsufficientOutputAmount();
        _safeTransferFrom(
            path[0],
            msg.sender,
            KswapLibrary.pairFor(address(factory), path[0], path[1]),
            amounts[0]
        );
        _swap(amounts, path, to);
    }

    function swapTokensForExactTokens(
        uint256 amountOut,
        uint256 amountInMax,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to
    ) public returns (uint256[] memory amounts) {
        amounts = KswapLibrary.getAmountsIn(
            address(factory),
            amountOut,
            path
        );
        if (amounts[amounts.length - 1] > amountInMax)
            revert ExcessiveInputAmount();
        _safeTransferFrom(
            path[0],
            msg.sender,
            KswapLibrary.pairFor(address(factory), path[0], path[1]),
            amounts[0]
        );
        _swap(amounts, path, to);
    }

    //
    //
    //
    //  PRIVATE
    //
    //
    //

    function _swap(
        uint256[] memory amounts,
        address[] memory path,
        address to_
    ) internal {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < path.length - 1; i++) {
            (address input, address output) = (path[i], path[i + 1]);
            (address token0, ) = KswapLibrary.sortTokens(input, output);
            uint256 amountOut = amounts[i + 1];
            (uint256 amount0Out, uint256 amount1Out) = input == token0
                ? (uint256(0), amountOut)
                : (amountOut, uint256(0));
            address to = i < path.length - 2
                ? KswapLibrary.pairFor(address(factory), output, path[i + 2])
                : to_;
            IKswapPair(
                KswapLibrary.pairFor(address(factory), input, output)
            ).swap(amount0Out, amount1Out, to);
        }
    }

    function _calculateLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint256 amountADesired,
        uint256 amountBDesired,
        uint256 amountAMin,
        uint256 amountBMin
    ) internal returns (uint256 amountA, uint256 amountB) {
        (uint256 reserveA, uint256 reserveB) = KswapLibrary.getReserves(
            address(factory),
            tokenA,
            tokenB
        );

        if (reserveA == 0 && reserveB == 0) {
            (amountA, amountB) = (amountADesired, amountBDesired);
        } else {
            uint256 amountBOptimal = KswapLibrary.quote(
                amountADesired,
                reserveA,
                reserveB
            ); //calculates output amount
            if (amountBOptimal <= amountBDesired) {
                if (amountBOptimal <= amountBMin) revert InsufficientBAmount();
                (amountA, amountB) = (amountADesired, amountBOptimal);
            } else {
                uint256 amountAOptimal = KswapLibrary.quote(
                    amountBDesired,
                    reserveB,
                    reserveA
                );
                assert(amountAOptimal <= amountADesired);

                if (amountAOptimal <= amountAMin) revert InsufficientAAmount();
                (amountA, amountB) = (amountAOptimal, amountBDesired);
            }
        }
    }

    function _safeTransferFrom(
        address token,
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 value
    ) private {
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = token.call(
            abi.encodeWithSignature(
                "transferFrom(address,address,uint256)",
                from,
                to,
                value
            )
        );
        if (!success || (data.length != 0 && !abi.decode(data, (bool))))
            revert SafeTransferFailed();
    }

    //
    //
    //        LIBRARY FUNCTIONS
    //
    //

    function quote(
        uint256 amountIn,
        uint256 reserveIn,
        uint256 reserveOut
    ) public pure returns (uint256 amountOut) {
        return KswapLibrary.quote(amountIn, reserveIn, reserveOut);
    }

    function getAmountOut(
        uint256 amountIn,
        uint256 reserveIn,
        uint256 reserveOut
    ) public pure returns (uint256 amountOut) {
        return KswapLibrary.getAmountOut(amountIn, reserveIn, reserveOut);
    }

    function getAmountIn(
        uint256 amountOut,
        uint256 reserveIn,
        uint256 reserveOut
    ) public pure returns (uint256 amountIn) {
        return KswapLibrary.getAmountIn(amountOut, reserveIn, reserveOut);
    }

    function getAmountsOut(uint256 amountIn, address[] memory path)
        public
        returns (uint256[] memory amounts)
    {
        return KswapLibrary.getAmountsOut(address(factory), amountIn, path);
    }

    function getAmountsIn(uint256 amountOut, address[] memory path)
        public
        returns (uint256[] memory amounts)
    {
        return KswapLibrary.getAmountsIn(address(factory), amountOut, path);
    }
}
```